# nginx.conf - passenger_env_var not loading in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I defined environment variables in nginx.conf like below -

```
 server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  XX.XX.XX.XX; //Masked for this question

        location ~ ^/clients/abc(/.*|$) {
                alias /home/abc/Project/public$1;
                passenger_base_uri /clients/abc;
                passenger_app_root /home/abc/Project;
                passenger_document_root /home/abc/Project/public;
                passenger_enabled on;
                passenger_env_var AWS_U disha;
        }
}
```

I restarted nginx but when I open `rails c` and type `ENV['AWS_U']`, it returns `nil`.

What possibly could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you move `passenger_enabled on;` `passenger_env_var AWS_U disha;` outside of `location` and into `server` block.

Answer (score 2):

U need to move `passenger_env_var` directive to `server` section.

```
server {
   ...
   passenger_env_var VAR value;
}
```

Comment: The reference https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/config/nginx/reference/#passenger_env_var
says that this directive can be used in the location context. When I tried using this directive in both the server and location contexts, it worked. In my opinion, the questioner has encountered another problem.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are only set when the application gets loaded by Passenger. They are not set when the application starts by `rails c` command.

If you want to know the value of an environment varialbe on the running application loaded by Passenger, you can make a temporal action for debugging:

```
class DebugController < ApplicationController
  def foobar
    render plain: "FOOBAR = '#{ENV['FOOBAR']}'"
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/debug/foobar" => "debug#foobar"
end
```